# Unicode characters in java

Tags: java, unicode, character

We have an **unicode processing** for the **primitive datatype char**,it follows the literals with single quote for ex,
for example :

```
psvm(String[] a)
              {
                char dollar='\u0024';
                char a='100';
                System.out.print(dollar);
                System.out.println(a);
             }
```

it will give output as $100,now my question is that please tell me the unicode for others spl characters and please provide for the indian currency symbol unicode. Hope you will help me. Kindly list whatever the unicodes u know for this kind of spl characters let me know

Comment: [This link may help you](http://bit.ly/R2n4am)

Comment: I am afraid about `char a='100';` does it work on your machine? which version of java are you using?

Answer (score 4):

use the following link that provides all character uniocde [code](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).and indian rupee symbol code is \u20B9 or read [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Rupee sign has been added in Unicode very recently in 2010, It is U+20B9 ₹ and in HTML: &#8377

```
char dollar='\u20B9';
String a="100";
System.out.print(dollar);
System.out.println(a);
```

I am afraid but It may show "?" instead of that unicode sign it is because of the showing character encoding of your IDE. So you may need to fix something on your properties or preference depending on your IDE.